# AWS RDS endpoint address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is the endpoint address of RDS instances unique across whole of AWS infrastructure irrespective of datacenter/VPC?

e.g:

```
aws.xxxx.yyy.rds.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 5):

Every unique RDS instance has a unique endpoint, regardless whether the instance is public or private.

The RDS endpoint is comprised of:

- The selected RDS instance ID,
- An account + region specific hash,
- The region ID
- ".rds.amazonaws.com"

The account + region specific hash is constant for all RDS instances in the same region and the same AWS account.

Comment: a DB engineer during an AWS support call verified that the `account + region specific hash` string is _" is region specific and is static"._ in case you wondering if it would change for your region and account (and service).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's unique. It has to be since you can make the database publicly accessible and connect to it directly over the Internet via the endpoint address.

Comment: Thanks. But if it is not publicly accessible, even then is it true?

Comment: Yes. The endpoint doesn't change based on it being public or not.